# ¿Cómo visualizar el nombre en lugar del ID?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, formularios, eloquent

Tengo una tabla en donde están registrados unos datos de las tablas relacionadas pero lo que quiero es mostrar el nombre en lugar del id esto es lo que he intentado hasta el momento pero no logro obtener resultados

**Imagen de resultados:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el error que me sale pero no logro comprenderlo bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modelos:**

```
class headform extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="pruebas";

    public function linea ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(linea::class, 'id_maquina');
    }
}

class linea extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="MAQUINA";

    public function prueba ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(headform::class);

    }
}
```

En este modelo hago la relación de que la pruebas puede tener muchas maquinas.

**Controlador:**

```
@foreach ($listform as $list)
<tr>
    <td>{{$list->codigo_formulario}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->lote}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->linea->nombre_maquina}}</td>
  <td>{{$list->producto_tamaño}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->fecha_empaque}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->ingeniero}}</td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Blade:**

```
@foreach ($listform as $list)
<tr>
    <td>{{$list->codigo_formulario}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->lote}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->maquina}}</td>
  <td>{{$list->producto_tamaño}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->fecha_empaque}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->ingeniero}}</td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-check-all"></i>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-xs">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Todo lo que he consultado no le probado pero no me sale ya tengo las relaciones de las tablas pero no  me trae el nombre tengo entendido que también se puede hacer con *JQuery* pero no tiene sentido si en *Laravel* se puede hacer esto o si alguien tiene una referencia de un caso similar agradecería la ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres que se carguen todas las pruebas con sus máquinas relacionadas?

Comment: gracias por responder si señor que en lugar que aparesca el id de la maquina se muestre el nombre de la maquina las tablas estan relacionadas

Comment: Agrega por favor tu otro modelo y la relación que en el definiste, entonces hablamos de que una *prueba tiene muchas máquinas* y varias máquinas pertenecen a una prueba?

Comment: si señor una prueba tiene muchas pero la verdad no estoy seguro de la segunda el modelo prueba es donde almaceno los datos de un formulario  y con este traigo  los datos de todo el formulario que esta repartido en varias tablas entonces el modelo prueba guarda los datos solo si existen las maquinas